# How to enqueue techs on Endless Space?

Tags: endless-space

If I choose some future advancement which has its prerequisites not yet researched I will enqueue more than one tech. Can I enqueue unrelated techs? How do I do it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One must **<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Left Click</kbd>** each in turn to queue up each technology in turn.  Without shift, it will reset the queue each time you click on a new technology.

I searched through the [Endless Space manual](http://cdn.steampowered.com/Manuals/208140/Endless%20Space%20User%20Manual%20Master%20EN.PDF?t=1355882060) on [Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/) and I couldn't find a reference to this, but it is discussed on [forums](http://www.octopusoverlords.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=81873&start=120).

Comment: It really bothers me that it's different from highlighting ships, `Ctrl` + `Left Click`.